# Copying annotations leads to a corrupted attachment

Tags: c#, plugins, encoding, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm implementing a plugin (POST Quote Create, Synchronous, Sandbox) to make it so that Notes are copied to the new record when a quote is revised.

My plugin boils down to this (snippet):

```
var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
var Service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

var notesQuery = new QueryExpression("annotation");
notesQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
notesQuery.Criteria = new FilterExpression
{
    FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
    Conditions =
    {
        new ConditionExpression("objecttypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, "quote"),
        new ConditionExpression("objectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, revisedQuoteId)
    }
};
var notes = Service.RetrieveMultiple(notesQuery).Entities;
foreach (var n in notes)
{
    var newNote = new Entity("annotation");

    newNote.Attributes.Add("ownerid", n.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("ownerid"));

    newNote.Attributes.Add("objectid", new EntityReference("quote", sourceEntity.Id));
    newNote.Attributes.Add("objecttypecode", "quote");

    newNote.Attributes.Add("subject", n.GetAttributeValue<string>("subject"));
    newNote.Attributes.Add("notetext", n.GetAttributeValue<string>("notetext"));

    newNote.Attributes.Add("isdocument", n.GetAttributeValue<bool>("isdocument"));

    if (n.GetAttributeValue<bool>("isdocument"))
    {
        newNote.Attributes.Add("filesize", n.GetAttributeValue<int>("filesize"));
        newNote.Attributes.Add("documentbody", n.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody"));
        newNote.Attributes.Add("filename", n.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename"));
        newNote.Attributes.Add("mimetype", n.GetAttributeValue<string>("mimetype"));
    }

    Service.Create(newNote);
}
```

Basically, I copy everything over, including an eventual attachment. Everything seems fine, the new revision shows fields, detail records and notes properly... everything *but the attachment* of the notes.

If I have a single note, with an attached `test.txt` which content is:

> Test attachment

The `OrganizationData` service reads as follows:

```
<d:FileName>test.txt</d:FileName>
<d:FileSize m:type="Edm.Int32">39</d:FileSize>        
<d:DocumentBody>H4sIAAAMaVMA/wtJLS5RSCwpSUzOyE3NK+HlAgCLmj1zEQAAAA==</d:DocumentBody>
```

Its "clone" has the correct subject and text, and also shows a `test.txt` attached which content is

> ‹  iS ÿI-.QH,)ILÎÈMÍ+áå ‹š=s

`mimetype` <strike>and `filesize`</strike> (while checking odata, I noticed that `filesize` is *not* actually correct!) appear to be correct (aka: the same as the original note I'm trying to copy), but OData seems to confirm something's off (it's different!):

```
<d:FileName>test.txt</d:FileName>
<d:FileSize m:type="Edm.Int32">60</d:FileSize
<d:DocumentBody>H4sIAED6aVMA/5Pv5mBg4MkMZvjP7amrF+iho+npc+6E71nth0+ZGLpn2RYLMjAwAABXqCwTJQAAAA==</d:DocumentBody>
```

The `test.txt` file was created from a command prompt (`COPY CON test.txt`, type, `CTRL+Z`).

I tried to change the file, and created a `test.pdf` through PDFCreator: AcroRead in turn whines and says the document is corrupted (so it seems like the issue is mimetype-agnostic).

I also tried re-implementing the same code through early binding (via the CRMSVCUTIL-generated classes) but it yields the exact same result (garbage instead of the attachment contents).

I attempted to hand-craft the `documentbody` like this:

```
// "VGVzdCBhdHRhY2htZW50" is Base64 for "Test attachment"
newNote.Attributes.Add("documentbody", "VGVzdCBhdHRhY2htZW50");
```

**and the created file is correct**.

I can't figure out what's going on: as far as I know, `documentbody` is supposed to be a Base64-encoded string which (again, as far as I know) shouldn't be any different when copied around. What am I missing ?

For reference, CRM is updated to **UR13** but I repro'd it on a **UR16** environment.

Comment: Have you inspected the value of `n.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody")`, and tried decoding to check the content?

Comment: I integrated my previous comments in the question. Latest addition: early-bound code doing the same thing yields the same result

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Does NOT work (only for CRM 4)**

Try this (not verified):

```
var notes = Service.RetrieveMultiple(notesQuery).Entities;
foreach (var newNote in notes)
{
    newNote.annotationid = null;

    newNote.Attributes.Add("objectid", new EntityReference("quote", sourceEntity.Id));
    newNote.Attributes.Add("objecttypecode", "quote");

    Service.Create(newNote);
}
```

Comment: CRM doesn't seem to like this approach (retrieve record, clear id, change objectid, re-create), I get either "Invalid argument" (if I nullify the id) or "duplicate error" (if I *remove* the id attribute from newNote, along with createdon, modifiedon, etc.)

Comment: the string "Test attachment" encoded in base64 is "VGVzdCBhdHRhY2htZW50". Can you try (just for testing purposes to narrow errorcause) newNote.Attributes.Add("documentbody","VGVzdCBhdHRhY2htZW50");

Comment: and btw: filesize its also strange. "Test attachment" length is 15 chars, so a file with this content is about 15bytes if ascii encoded, 18 bytes if utf8 encoded and 32bytes if utf-16 encoded. 39 or 60 bytes filesize seems not be nonsens.

Comment: Hand-crafting documentbody like that produced the correct file contents in the note. I also reproduced the issue on a UR16 environment (amending question). I concur about the weird filesize but I'm at a loss here

Comment: ok, then for what reasons ever the statement n.GetAttributeValue<string>("documentbody") , thats means the source annotation, returns already garbage. Maybe you can print out the value via tracing service (or store the value in a textfield which is visible in the crm ui). Additionally you may look into the database with sql managementstudio whats stored in the documentbody field. Another question just be sure: is the user which executes the plugin allowed to read the documentbody field (check fieldlevel security prefs)?

Comment: Oh yeah, permissions are fine (i'm using a System Administrator user, and there is no field security involved). I'll check the database

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this, in an article from MSDN:

```
Annotation setupAnnotation = new Annotation()
{
  Subject = "Example Annotation",
  FileName = "ExampleAnnotationAttachment.txt",
  DocumentBody = Convert.ToBase64String(
  new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes("Sample Annotation Text")),
  MimeType = "text/plain"
};
```

I see the document body is encoded according to the Unicode encoding. Maybe you should try to retrieve the encoding from the file and convert it to a string accordingly.